# Intel XDK + SVN(Subversion)

Tags: svn, intel-xdk

Estou precisando de controlar a versão do meu código no Intel XDK, eu conheço o SVN, teria como de utiliza-lo no intel, ou tem outra forma de fazer com outro tipo de programa.

Preciso que uma equipe trabalhe no projeto e que venha atualizando para todos os que estão trabalhando a versão mais nova.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com o SVN é possível controlar versão de código, em formato texto, como Java, JavaScript, C, etc, e até versões de arquivos binários, como um código compilado.

Obviamente as vantagens são mais visiveis, do ponto de vista do desenvolvedor, controlar a versão do código.

Para saber mais sobre o svn de uma lida neste [artigo](http://intentor.com.br/svn-conceitos-boas-praticas-dicas-de-utilizacao/).

Portanto se o seu projeto se trata de um código, é sim possível você controlar com o SVN, você pode utilizar um [servidor pessoal](http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/9257-instalando-e-configurando-um-servidor-subversion-svn-no-debian), ou um [**SourceForge**](http://sourceforge.net/) por exemplo.

Você pode usar também outras ferramentas de controle de versão como **[Git](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Primeiros-passos-No%C3%A7%C3%B5es-B%C3%A1sicas-de-Git)**, caso seja um projeto OpenSource, com o [**GitHub**](https://github.com/), para projetos proprietários, uma opção é o [**BitBucket**](https://bitbucket.org/), gratuito para até 5 desenvolvedores.

Comment: Boa resposta, porem como faria para utilizar isto com o Intel XDK ?

Comment: De uma olhada nesta resposta no stack em inglês, aparentemente você pode usar um componente para Git: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25827460/1997073