# Versionamento de site local para VPS

Tags: versionamento

Qual ferramenta e serviços usar para versionar um site local e depois "commitar" para um VPS, por exemplo?

Comment: Será que está resposta não te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80028/5407

Comment: [Veja a Wiki da tag de versionamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/versionamento/info). É nela que você pode buscar informações. Tudo depende da necessidade que você tem: se o site ganha novas implementações com frequência, se o site é mantido por um ou mais usuários, e assim por diante.

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado, vou conferir. O site esta sendo atualizado, layout, etc.